# Execute javascript from parent on iframe

Tags: javascript

I appologize if I will not provide all the required info but there is just to much code to include here. If a simple answer is not possible I'll understand and will rebuilt my solution. I have this line of js:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

it is linked with a whole bunch of .css and .js files. Basically what it does is it reformats  to be like a calendar. I use it for IE and older versions of Firefox... and it works just fine for me.

What I need is to execute that line WITH all of the linked .css and .js files and properties from the parent on a datepicker class input that is in an iframe of my page. I cannot execute it from the iframe because that iframe carries other .css and .js files that cause a conflict with what I have going on in the parent.

If this is a stupid question I'll totally understand and again appologize .. but if you guys have a simple answer that would save me a LOT of work.

Comment: You would definitely have to include the relevant js and css in the iframe. Pages cannot modify each other's DOM directly.

Comment: @BrahmaDev  thanks buddy. I was afraid of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following example ...

Example :

```
https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html
```

CSS :

```
https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css
```

JS :

```
https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
```

USES :

```
//Datemask dd/mm/yyyy
$('#datemask').inputmask('dd/mm/yyyy', { 'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy' })
```

Comment: thanks, I'll give that solution a try. I just hope it does not cause a conflict with all the other js and css I have in the iframe. thank you